# Warning when a function in a derived class fails to override a virtual function in a base class

Tags: c++, gcc, g++, compiler-warnings

Consider the following little program:

```
#include <iostream>

class Base {
public:
    virtual void MyFunction() const {
        std::cout << "This is Base" << std::endl;
    }
};

class Derived : public Base {
public:
    virtual void MyFuntcion() {
        std::cout << "This is Derived" << std::endl;
    }
};

int main() {
    Base *p = new Derived();
    p->MyFunction();
    return 0;
}
```

it compiles cleanly with `g++ -Wall -Wextra` with nary a peep from the compiler, but when you run it, it prints "`This is Base`", due to the typo in the function name in Derived.

Now in java or C#, if you put an `@override` tag on the function, you'll get a warning from the compiler about the typo.  Is there any way to do something similar with gcc?  Perhaps a magic `__attribute__` or some such?

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/override

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C++11 introduced `override` as well

```
class Derived : public Base {
public:
    void MyFuntcion() override {
        std::cout << "This is Derived" << std::endl;
    }
};
```

```
test.cpp:12:10: error: 'void Derived::MyFuntcion()' marked 'override', but does not override
     void MyFuntcion() override {
```